# Does erlang record when a process started?

Tags: erlang

I'm working with monitoring an Erlang application and I'm currently trying to determine how long a specific PID has been running.  Absolute timestamp or duration would work for me, but I do not see either of those bits of data in process_info or via the sys module.  Is there a way to get this information from within the Erlang VM?

I can get the start time of the overall VM from the ps command, but that doesn't have any visibility of individual Erlang processes.

Edit:

I've noticed that when the VM crashes, the erl_crash.dump contains a started timestamp for each process, so I know it's in there!

Comment: Alternatively (and perhaps stating the obvious): You could persist the start date in the process state (in `gen_server:init`), and return the difference with `erlang:now` when asked.

Comment: Seconded, save that you should use `os:timestamp/0` instead of `erlang:now/0`. `now/0` unfortunately needs to acquire a global lock to guarantee that it's return is monotonically increasing and unique.

Comment: I'd love to do that, but it's not my application, I'm just monitoring it, so I can't make changes in the app itself.  I start a second VM and send it commands via rpc:call.

Comment: OK, I made a patch for Erlang: https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/1597

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr: yes, but you can't get to it.**

If you dig into the OTP source code at https://github.com/erlang/otp, you'll find (by searching for "erl_crash") that the file responsible for writing the crash dump is called `erts/emulator/beam/break.c`.

Searching that file for "started" (it's both a good guess, and it's what appears in the crash dump) will get you to [lines 248-249](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-18.3.1/erts/emulator/beam/break.c#L248-L249) (all line numbers based on the OTP-18.3.1 tag), which look like this:

```
approx_started = (time_t) p->approx_started;
erts_print(to, to_arg, "Started: %s", ctime(&approx_started));
```

Searching the rest of the source code for `approx_started` shows it being declared in `erts/emulator/beam/erl_process.h` as a member of `struct process`. It is *written* in `erts/emulator/beam/erl_process.c`. The **only** place it is *read* is in `break.c`, when writing the crash dump.

So, yes, Erlang *does* record the (approximate) time that a process was started. But, no, you can't get to it.

I have no idea why it's "approximate".

Answer (score 4):

Write a process which manages this. Since you can find the PID of the given process, you can also set a `monitor` on the process. Then, if the process errors out, you will get a message in your mailbox.

I would guess this could form the basis for a solution for you.

Comment: Yes, this is an excellent way to be notified when the PID dies.  But I'm also trying to find when it started.

Comment: However, if this is for metrics, do you have any guarantee of how timely is the monitor going to be called after the process has died? Could it be 2 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking in toolbar:start(). the process monitor and don't look time alive or time init, but it is easy to make. In dictionary of process you can save a value when init and that this process can respond to other process about this value.

For read value in dictionary process you can use get/1 and for save use put/2 (first key and second value).

Respond to other process about this value is same that others responses, etc.

Comment: This would definitely work, but would require changing the application itself.  I can submit this as a feature request, but I can't make that change myself.

Comment: If you need this for a aplication that not development you and you use from your aplication, I recommend submit this as feature but not to aplication development else to Erlang VM developments. I think that is interesting.