# Getting the uptime of an elixir process

Tags: process, elixir, pid, uptime

Given the `pid`, is it possible to get the uptime, or creation datetime, of an elixir process?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36555845/320615

Comment: Given the answers to the above, I'll try baking the creation date into the process name.

Comment: If you're spawning the process yourself, this might be a good place to use per process state using `Process.put` and `Process.get`.

Comment: Really don't get those functions - the `pid` isn't passed in - are there any examples of them being used anywhere?